# Restore in app without buying

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, itunes, storekit

I am working on an application which also supports a few functionality which can be purchased through In-app. I have provided two buttons, Buy and Restore, meaning literally.

I have a very basic concern, what if the user presses the Restore button and when asked for credential types in the credentials which never bought the In-App purchasable products. How am  I supposed to handle this condition? My understanding tells me that when the user presses the Restore button, we make a call to `restoreCompletedTransactions` which will try to restore the bought products and since in the case I am referring user has not purchased any product there is nothing to unlock. I think the store kit will handle it automatically and present with a buy option.

This is not working for me. If I use an account which never bought the In-app product and try to restore there is no response, none of the delegates are called. And on the other hand if I use the account which have purchased to restore, things work fine.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I am using test users and sandbox env.

Comment: Are you sure that you implement - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here:
[iOS in-app-purchase restore returns many transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912442/ios-in-app-purchase-restore-returns-many-transactions)

You'll have to handle it in transaction observer.

In short, you start restore process with:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Then following transaction observer is called:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    int thisIsTheTotalNumberOfPurchaseToBeRestored = queue.transactions.count;

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *thisIsProductIDThatHasAlreadyBeenPurchased = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        if([thisIsProductIDThatHasAlreadyBeenPurchased isEqualToString:product1ID])
        {
            //Enable product1 here
        }
    }
}
```