# iOS in-app-purchase restore returns many transactions

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, restore

When I am restoring my previous purchase. `Storekit` is calling `updateTransations` with large number of previous transactions. Don't know why it is returning these large amount like 100, 200 ,245, 360, 650 seems like random in every restore.

Is that happen in the sandbox only?
If no, what should be the criteria of selecting the item. I have many items with the same product id?

Comment: how do you restore the purchased items ? please check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120050/obj-c-storekit-restorecompletedtransactions-returns-zero-transactions/10121113#10121113)

Answer (score 2):

There have been a lot of complaints about using updateTransactions for restoring.  The below code will work but it requires the user to enter in their username and password.  (for now developers have been sticking this in a IBAction call which requires a button)

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Then the below delegate is called.

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
     for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) 
    {
        if ([myItem.productID isEqualToString:transaction.payment.productIdentifier])
        {
            myItem.purchased = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to do this without putting a "restore" button on my interface if there are no items that need to be restored.