# Restoring an in app purchase with a user who never paid for it

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to test the in app purchase in my app.

When i restore the in app purchase with a test user who bought the in app purchase it all works fine.

But when i try to restore an in app purchase with a user who **didn't** make the in app purchase before i expected the framework to call the following method:

`-paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:`

but instead the framework calls:

`-paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:`

like my test user already bought the in app purchase....

Is this the normal behavior? And if so, how do i test a user trying to restore without ever purchasing the in app purchase?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the answer here:
[iOS in-app-purchase restore returns many transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912442/ios-in-app-purchase-restore-returns-many-transactions)

You'll have to handle it in transaction observer.

In short, you start restore process with:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Then following transaction observer is called:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    int thisIsTheTotalNumberOfPurchaseToBeRestored = queue.transactions.count;

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *thisIsProductIDThatHasAlreadyBeenPurchased = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        if([thisIsProductIDThatHasAlreadyBeenPurchased isEqualToString:product1ID])
        {
            //Enable product1 here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try MKStoreKit framework https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit
It is pretty good, well maintained framework. I have a few apps with in-app purchases. Never had any issues like that.

Comment: can you send link. how to use this sources, because on Kumar blog there is complex description how to use it. is there any other way how to include this sources to project? but I know this sourses is the best and many my friend use it as well.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no demo project because you have to set up a couple of things in your app. It takes a few hours to make it work but it's mostly figuring out how to set up your app for app purchase. The github link is your best source for information. Google search shows an outdated blog post.

Answer (score 0):

@Tibidabo I wouldn't recommend MKStoreKit because it has a big [hole](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/pull/146) in restore purchased items functionality.