# Test account restores unpurchased products in MKStoreKit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mkstorekit

I've created a new test account to test restore option in the latest MKStoreKit, I didn't purchase this item "non-consumable item" neither using the new test account nor using any other test account. Still it gave me  a restore success answer and executed the onComplete code block.
My question: Is it a normal behavior for a test account to restore non-purchased products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a normal behaviour, please notice that onComplete code block in restore method will execute wither the account has purchased this product before or not, onComplete here indicates that the user has logged in successfully, request has been sent to apple and it received a response back.
It's better to provide content after the check not onComplete, please refer to this answer for more details: [Restoring an in app purchase with a user who never paid for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086179/restoring-an-in-app-purchase-with-a-user-who-never-paid-for-it/11241869#11241869)

Answer (score 0):

MKStoreKit has a big hole in restore purchased items functionality.
For more details go [here](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/pull/146).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.